のは, ので, のか with stress on の?
In a Youtube video, I came across various instances of の being stressed where I wouldn't have expected it to be. As far as I am aware, downsteps in pitch don't (ever?) occur directly after nominalizer の, but I'm not sure if this is a matter of pitch accent in the first place.
There are also many instances in the video where the speaker does not stress the の.
Is this a common phenomenon?
section with のは
section with ので
section with のか

His accent is weird in other parts, too.

I would say this type of accent can be grouped in with a certain type of speech that is common in politics. It’s a specific type of “extra accent” that’s added at one mora before the end of the accent clause for emphasis. For example you can hear あき＼らかに turn into あき＼らか＼に where the か is actually pronounced at a higher pitch than the き. Sort of like LMLHL. Off the top of my head, one such person who does this often is 河野太郎, feel free to watch some of his speeches if you want more examples (e.g., 0:36 has it twice in a row here).
Tokyo natives do this so I think it’s hard to claim it’s dialectal. But it is uncommon, so I wouldn’t recommend copying it if you want to sound like you have a neutral accent.

This is more like an idiosyncratic habit of this particular speaker, and should not be taken as a common way of speaking in any well-known dialect or speech style. (A native speaker will notice that he is not a professional announcer or seiyū within a few seconds.)
